# How to handle a string that comes from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsarray

Im initializing a string from an URL as follow:

```
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:TheUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

The URL contains an s19 file, it seems like follow:

```
S111C019600FBDC09138BDC0353FBDFFCD16D0
S111C0272B024F3986FF393617BDFFB8323968
S110C035308F83000C8F35CCC350ED0AFD15
S111C0426000ED04ED02EC04ED00CCC08ABDFC
```

after this line I got the data into my text string. then I want to split the string to get an hex array, how can I do that? I was using the next line to get an array but It gives me the next (and it is right):

```
NSArray *arr = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
arr[0] --> S111C019600FBDC09138BDC0353FBDFFCD16D0
```

How can I split my text string into bytes/words values? something like this:

```
arr[0] --> C0
arr[1] --> 19
arr[2] --> 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and `substringWithRange:`, building up the range location as you iterate. The length of the range dictates how much you're taking from the original string on each iteration.

---

Something along the lines of:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 2);

while (range.location + range.length < sourceString.length) {
    [array addObject:[sourceString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location += range.length;
}
```

Comment: Hi Wain, can you provide a code example? Im new on this thanks!